# How to set up an SSH connection to a MySQL database in Airflow?

Tags: mysql, ssh, airflow

I am trying to connect to a database using an SSH connection. However, when I try to add a connection, I do not see fields that allow me to set up an SSH connection. I am aware that one can pass extra parameters, but am not sure what key values does Airflow accept for my use case.

Comment: If you’re planning on using the `MySQLOperator` or `MySQLHook` with this connection, there is no support for this. Ideally you would just run an Airflow worker where you are trying to ssh to or just connect to the MySQL instance remotely. But if you must, there is an SSHHook and SSHOperator that allows execution of commands on remote hosts which might be what you’re looking for.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you are trying to connect to a database using SSH? do you simply want to SSH to the server that the database is running on or make a connection to the database with JDBC etc?

Comment: @SimonD, I want to make a connection with JDBC, much similar to how DataGrip/MYSQL Workbench does. Having read around previously, it seems that airflow doesn't allow this currently, unless there have been recent changes since the time I asked this question.

Comment: **@DanielHuang**, **@SimonD**, any updates on this? It's a massive shortcoming not to provide support for remote `MySQL` hosts. And what are the suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

Airflow currently (itself) does not allow SSH connection. With airflow's `Extra` params you can only encrypt your connection (which btw. is a good idea).

So if you're interested in encrypted connection, in `Extra` fields you need to specify parameters like that:

`"cert":"/path/to/certs/client-cert.pem", "key":"/path/to/certs/client-key.pem", "ca":"/path/to/certs/server-ca.pem"}`

In details, if you "dig" `MySqlOperator` you will see following chain:

- `MySqlOperator` uses `MySqlHook`
- `MySqlHook` uses python's mysql library `MySQLdb`
- `MySQLdb` is an interface to C version which has function `mysql_ssl_set()` described here in details:
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-ssl-set.html

This link nicely explains what `cert`, `key` and `ca` are and what should be put in there.

---

Now, if that's still not what you want then you need to "step out" of the Airflow. Assuming that you can already ssh to your server (`ssh username@your-host`) then, in separate terminal window (or background) you should launch forwarding using command: `ssh -L <bind_address>:127.0.0.1:<host_port> username@your-host` where:

- `<bind_address>` is port on which you will locally connect your Airflow
- `<host_port>` is port on which your remote host's database listens on (so for mysql it's `3306`)

When your forwarding is in place, you can use Airflow's `Connections` settings and specify connection that will use `localhost` as your `Host` and `<bind_address>` as `Port`.

Example: Let's say your remote database listens on port `3306` and working ssh connection is `ssh me@my-host`. Your forwarding command should be e.g. `ssh -L 9876:127.0.0.1:3306` and Airflow's settings:

- `Host`: `localhost`
- `Port`: `9876`
- all other connection settings are similar to connecting to mysql database on your localhost

Keep in mind that your forwarding session has to be "ON" all the time, otherwise the connection will break. Just put it in background.